# google fit android api get sleep data

Tags: android, kotlin, google-fit

I'm going to use Google Fit's Android api to get the data.

I was able to get the data related to the number of steps I used for the first time, but I couldn't get the data when I tried to get the sleep data.

How can I get the fit sleep data normally?

I was wondering if it was a problem with Google oAuth, so I checked the settings of OAuth 2.0 Scopes again, but I couldn't confirm the problem.

Is there anyone who can tell me a good way?

Below is my current code.

'''

//init

```
    val account = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(context, fitnessOptions)
    if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, fitnessOptions).not()) {
        GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(
            this, // your activity
            GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE, // e.g. 1
            account,
            fitnessOptions
        )
    } else {
        accessGoogleFit(account)
    }
```

//function

```
private fun accessGoogleFit(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
    val eT = java.util.Calendar.getInstance()
    val sT = java.util.Calendar.getInstance()
    eT.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
    sT.timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()
    sT.set(2021, 11, 22, 0, 0, 0)
    eT.set(2021, 12, 22, 23, 59, 59)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
        val startTime = LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        val endTime = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())


        val endSeconds = eT.timeInMillis
        val startSeconds = sT.timeInMillis

        val datasource = DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName("com.google.android.gms")
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .setStreamName("estimated_steps")
            .build()

        val request = DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(datasource)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime.toEpochSecond(), endTime.toEpochSecond(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()


        val sleepingE = LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        val sleepingS = endTime.minusWeeks(1)
        val readRequest = SessionReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeInterval(
                sleepingS.toEpochSecond(),
                sleepingE.toEpochSecond(),
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            )
            .read(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            .setSessionName("sleeping")
            .build()

        Fitness.getHistoryClient(
            activity,
            GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(activity, fitnessOptions)
        )
            .readData(request)
            .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
                val totalSteps = response.buckets
                    .flatMap { it.dataSets }
                    .flatMap { it.dataPoints }
                    .sumBy { it.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt() }
                vm.googleFitSteps.value = totalSteps
            }
            .addOnCanceledListener {

            }

        Fitness.getSessionsClient(activity,account).readSession(readRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener { response ->
                for (session in response.sessions) {
                    val sessionStart = session.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    val sessionEnd = session.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    Log.e("googleFit", "Sleep between $sessionStart and $sessionEnd")

                    // If the sleep session has finer granularity sub-components, extract them:
                    val dataSets = response.getDataSet(session)
                    for (dataSet in dataSets) {
                        for (point in dataSet.dataPoints) {
                            val sleepStageVal = point.getValue(Field.FIELD_SLEEP_SEGMENT_TYPE).asInt()
                            val sleepStage = SLEEP_STAGE_NAMES[sleepStageVal]
                            val segmentStart = point.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            val segmentEnd = point.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            Log.e("googleFit", "\t* Type $sleepStage between $segmentStart and $segmentEnd")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e("googleFit", "Failed to read session error :$e", e)
            }

  
    } else {
        showAlertDialog("지원되지 않는 휴대폰입니다.", {
            vm.setSyncHealthApp(false)
            vm.checkHealthAppSync.value = false
        })
    }

}
```

'''

Comment: If things were properly set, and you don’t think there is any error in the codes or OAuth scopes. Try to disconnect your app from Google Fit, this will reset any connection with your app and start fresh. Just open Google Fit app > Settings > Manage connected apps.

You can also verify backend responses and to preview an authentication flow  from the Google Fit using OAuth Playground https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/get-started#try_the_rest_api_in_the_oauth_playground.